# Intersection of maximal subgroup with subgroup is maximal in subgroup?

Tags: group-theory

As soon as it looks obvious one way, it looks obvious the other way: if $G$ is a group, $M$ is maximal subgroup and $N$ is subgroup of G, is $M\cap N$ maximal subgroup of $N$? What if $N\lhd G$?

In last case I thought: $M/(M\cap N)\cong MN/N\le G/N\;$ ...but I can't continue.

Other condition: same question if we assume $N\lhd G$ is of finite index...? Then in the above we have $G/N\;$ finite group, so $\;M/N\le G/N\;$ also finite...but still stuck.

Any help/direction will be thanked.

Comment: There are pathological counterexamples:

Take $N = 1$. Then $M \cap 1 = 1$ will not be maximal in $N$ since maximal subgroups are proper.

Comment: Why aren't you ruling out $M=N$ or $N=1$?

Comment: @ε-δ I think proper argument is $1$ is properly contained in a proper subgroup $\langle a \rangle $ (say) where $a$ is non-trivial element in $N$

Answer (score 5):

Let $G=S_4$, $M=S_3$ and $N=V_4$. Clearly $M$ is a maximal subgroup of $G$, and $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. Also, $M\cap N=1$ is not maximal in $N$.

Comment: Thank you. Trivial intersection makes the cut in this case, certainly.

Answer (score 3):

Obvious counterexamples are when $M\ge N$, so let's assume that's not the case.

In no case is this true. For a finite example take $G=S\times S$ with $S$ simple and non-abelian (e.g. $A_5$), $N=S\times\{1\}$ and $M$ the diagonal subgroup $\{(g,g)|g\in S\}$.

It's a nice exercise to show $M$ is maximal in $G$, but $M\cap N=1$ is clearly not maximal in $N$

Comment: Thank you. Very nice example.